# How Insert Data from R to SQL

Tags: sql, r, odbc

With `library(RODBC)`

I used this sentence:

```r
sqlUpdate(myconn, 'UPDATE "VALUE" SET IP_INPUT_VALUE = "0.01"')
```

The error is :

> should be a data frame or matrix

Comment: Just curious: the table you're trying to update is named `"VALUE"`? Youe `IP_INPUT_VALUE` is a string?

Comment: The names was change , is other name and take the sentes of SELECT with IP_INPUT_VALUE . This is a number

Comment: I need to now how make  sql INSERT sentece from Rstudio with RODBC to sql server

Comment: I use `library(DBI)`. For example: `dbSendStatement(myconn, "INSERT INTO my_table (speed, dist) VALUES (10, 20)", params = list(4L, 5L) )`.